# constructor syntax missing formal parameters

Tags: c++, class-template

I am writing a class template that contains an array of objects.
I am getting an error that says "constructor syntax missing formal parameters".
The error is associated with the line of code DT List[100];

```
template <class DT>
class List
{
private:
    DT List[100];
    int numberInList;
    int listSize;
    int nextIndex;
public:
    List();
    void insert(DT&);
    DT getNext();
    bool getMember(DT&);
    int getNumber();
};
#endif

template<class DT>
List<DT>::List()
{
   numberInList = 0;
   listSize = 0;
   nextIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* output of the compiler into the question body.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a variable with the same name as the class? That cannot work well

Answer (score 0):

For future readers (as noted by @UnholySheep in the comments), the problem most likely stemmed from the member `DT List[100];`. The name of the class is `List` as well as the name of the member. This likely caused some parsing confusion. Changing the name of the member variable should resolve the error.